# Nitrogen - File upload

Tags: erlang, yaws, nitrogen

I can easily upload a file using Nitrogen's `#upload{}` element, it works great.

However, I am using client side Javascript to create an html file upload form (not using `#upload{}` tag in Nitrogen .erl file), and not able to get it to work.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

EDIT: I am using Nitrogen on top of Yaws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [element_upload.erl](https://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen_core/blob/master/src/elements/forms/element_upload.erl) file as reference for how to interface with files uploaded using a standard html form.

Basically, you'll need to get the request bridge from the context, then get the list of files from the request bridge.

```
Req = wf_context:request_bridge(),
UploadedFiles = Req:post_files(),
```

The uploadedFiles is a list of `#sb_uploaded_file` records, with the attributes `original_name`, and `temp_file`. You can see the details in the [simple_bridge header](https://github.com/nitrogen/simple_bridge/blob/master/include/simple_bridge.hrl)

From there, you can copy the files elsewhere, or do whatever you need to do with them.

Edit: The uploaded file interface has been improved in simple_bridge and no longer requires including the header file, instead recommending using the [sb_uploaded_file](https://github.com/nitrogen/simple_bridge/blob/master/src/sb_uploaded_file.erl) module for interfacing with the uploaded files.